# R rhyper() fails to give correct hypergeometric random number

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to generate some random numbers from hypergeometric distribution using R. However, the rhyper() behaves very strange when I have a very small number of white balls and a large number for black balls.  Here is what I got in my computer:

```
> sum(rhyper(100,1000,1e9-1000,1e6))
[1] 91
> sum(rhyper(100,2000,1e9-2000,1e6))
[1] 204
> sum(rhyper(100,10000,1e9-10000,1e6))
[1] 1016
> sum(rhyper(100,20000,1e9-20000,1e6))
[1] 1909
> sum(rhyper(100,50000,1e9-50000,1e6))
[1] 4968
> sum(rhyper(100,5000,1e9-5000,1e6))
[1] 60
> sum(rhyper(100,6000,1e9-6000,1e6))
[1] 164
> sum(rhyper(100,8000,1e9-8000,1e6))
[1] 0
> sum(rhyper(100,9000,1e9-9000,1e6))
[1] 45
```

The first 5 works fine, but for the 6th, I expected to get a number around 500, but not something like 60, also for the 7th,8th,9th.

Something wrong with the rhyper() function or my computer?

Comment: Even stranger; Look at `sum(rhyper(100,3000,1e9-3000,1e6));  sum(rhyper(100,4000,1e9-4000,1e6))`